# Laravel 4.1 Querying multiple databases. I need OneToMany Polymorphic relation - does it exist?

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I wonder if you can help me, I was very excited around the release of Laravel 4.1 as I was sure that the new polymorphic relationships would solve a little development problem I had on the Horizon. Unfortunately, despite my best efforts I'm unable to bend any of the existing relationships to my will.

Essentially what I want is a one to many polymorphic relationship, so that I can "join" a query to any number of models, which can have different databases connections - I would like this to happen within Eloquent.

Unfortunately this relationship, to my surprise, doesn't seem to exist. All the polymorphic relationships I have seen require at least an entry on the polymorphic table for every entry on the connecting table - huge unnecessary data duplication for my purposes - and largely defeating the point of what I'm trying to do.

Below is what I have come up with as a work around but I dont want to start churning out custom code I have to maintain if I don't have to and I'm sure this must be possible. Does anyone know how to do this without resorting to the code below, also interested in tips to improve code for possible pull request if non-existent:

```
public function morphOneToMany($foreignKey, $localKey, $name = null, $type = null, $id = null)
    {

        if (is_null($name))
        {
            list(, $caller) = debug_backtrace(false);

            $name = snake_case($caller['function']);
        }

        list($type, $id) = $this->getMorphs($name, $type, $id);

        $class = $this->$type;
        return $this->hasMany($class, $foreignKey, $localKey);
    }
```

More details on laravel forums: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=16677